# Change URL depending on browser language

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an English-based website and have a button with the URL https://subdomain.website.com that leads to the website subdomain:

```
<a href="https://subdomain.website.com" id="subdomainURL">Title</a>
```

How can I add a Google Translate append like `#googtrans(en|fr)` to this URL depending on the user's browser language so if the user's browser language is French by default the URL will change to the `https://subdomain.website.com#googtrans(en|fr)`. And similarly if user uses another language the URL append will change according to his browser default language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [navigator.language](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage) like this:

```
var lang = navigator.language.slice(0,2);
var el = document.getElementById('subdomainURL');
var href = `${el.href}#googtrans(en|${lang})`;
el.href = href;
```

Answer (score 0):

[`navigator.language`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/language) is the way to get user's locales, here is a working snippet:

```js
console.log(navigator.language)
const lang = window.navigator.language.slice(0, 2);
if ( lang === 'en') {       
  // you can set the href attribute value based on language:
  document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach((el) => {
    el.setAttribute('href', `${el.getAttribute('href')}#googtrans(en|${lang})`)
  });
}
```

```html
<a href="https://subdomain.website.com" id="subdomainURL">Title</a>
```